# Totals and subtotals in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Pivot table data has the following structure:
    # Person A            Quantity #
        ##   Category X           10 ##
        ##   Category Y           20 ##
        ##   Category Z           25 ##
    # Person A Total          55 #
    # Person B                   #
        ##   Category X           30 ##
        ##   Category Y           15 ##
        ##   Category Z            0 ##
    # Person B Total          45 #
    # Grand Total            100 #

Is it possible to have Grand Total in the structure shown below:
    # Grand Total            100 #
        ##    Category X          40 ##
        ##    Category Y          35 ##
        ##    Category Z          25 ##
Just grand totals by the values of second labels in pivot table rows. 
[image]
Pic1 as it is now.
[image]
Pic2 as required.

Comment: what are you field names ?

Comment: Person / Category / Quantity

Comment: Not in the same pivot in the way you have shown. Your bottom few rows you have shown are without person in the row field whereas the top is with. You cannot simultaneously have this field present and not present, except in in some Schrödinger universe.

Answer (score 0):

I can get to this:

[image]

...by first turning this:

[image]

...into this:

[image]

Which I then use for the Pivot Table:

[image]

I chose for Subtotals to "Show all Subtotals at Top of Group" and turned Grand Totals "Off for Rows and Columns".

I used Power Query to make the new table that I used for the Pivot Table. For that, I used the original table (Table1) as the source. Then I did Transform -> Group By, with these settings:

[image]

Then I did Add Column -> Custom Colum, with these settings:

[image]

Then I did Home -> Append Queries, with these settings:

[image]

Then, in the formula bar, I changed this:

[image]

...to this:

[image]

*#"Changed Type" points to the earlier Applied Query Step that was the last "version" of the original table. This appends the most recent "version" (#"Added Custom") with it. It appends the #"Added Custom" "query" to the #"Changed Type" "query".*

Then Home -> Close and Load to close Power Query and load the new table into a new tab in your spreadsheet. That's the table to use for your Pivot Table.